# SQL query returns different number of rows depending on the columns selected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Thanks for the contributions so far. After more digging I am re-stating the question (and indeed the title of the question) as follows:

I am selecting just 2 columns from a view that contains several columns. The view returns 50,497 rows if I select all columns, but only  50,496 (i.e. 1 fewer) when I select just 2 columns, these being [Patient_ID] (which is a bigint column) and [Condition_Code] (a varchar(6) column).

Version 1:

```
SELECT * FROM [vw_Query1]
```

> returns 50,497 rows.

But:

```
SELECT [Patient_ID], [Condition_Code] FROM [vw_Query1]
```

> returns 50,496 rows.

I can post the code for `[vw_Query1]` if required, but an understanding at a fundamental level how this can happen when no GROUP BY clause has been used is the key question for me.

UPDATE:

It turns out that if I exclude one particular column, I get the lower number of rows of 50,496. This column is unique in having a Case-Sensitive collation. I still dont understand why it is dropping one particular row but at least I am getting closer to an understanding.

Comment: You might need to post your function, sample data and expected results.  As is, it's not really possible for us to help (nor does it make much sense -- `select * from table` will return everything in that table -- `where` filters on those results, doesn't add to them).  Can you create a `sqlfiddle.com` demonstrating your problem?

Comment: There's something in your query that's causing the behavior.   We'd need to see the code to help you understand what it is.

Comment: You say you have a `join`. That's almost definitely where you record is being dropped.

Comment: A `WHERE` clause cannot cause a row to appear that is not output without the `WHERE` clause.  If I had to guess, you are confused because the patient ids are not output in any particular order.

Comment: As an exercise in surfacing the problem, what's the first row that comes back from the query `SELECT [Patient_ID],[Condition] FROM myQuery ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Patient_ID] = 123456789 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`?

Comment: Thanks all. I've reduced the problem to its simplest form and the resulting code is shown below. By way of background, I am trying to find the rows contained in CTE1 but not in CTE2. CTE1 does contain the Patient_ID of interest but CTE2 does not, so I am expecting to find it in the output.

Comment: WITH CTE1 AS (

SELECT [Patient_ID]
      ,[Condition_Code]
FROM [Query1]
-- Note: DOES contain Patient_ID = 13413953

), CTE2 AS (

SELECT [Patient_ID]
      ,[QOF_Condition_Code] AS [Condition_Code]
FROM [dbo].[Query2]
-- Note: Does NOT contain Patient_ID = 13413953

), CTE3 AS (

SELECT CTE1.[Patient_ID]
      ,CTE1.[Condition_Code]
FROM CTE1
LEFT JOIN CTE2
ON CTE1.[Patient_ID] = CTE2.[Patient_ID]
AND CTE1.[Condition_Code] = CTE2.[Condition_Code]
WHERE CTE2.[Patient_ID] IS NULL

)

SELECT 
  [Patient_ID]
 ,[Condition_Code]
FROM CTE3

Comment: The result of this query is 141 rows that do not contain Patient_ID 13413953. However if I add WHERE Patient_ID = 13413953 at the very end the single row is returned containing this ID.

Comment: And per Matt Gibsons suggestion, the result of applying the CASE WHEN adjustment returns Patient 13491354 as the first row.

Comment: Update the question.  Don't jam your query in comment.

Comment: @JBrog And with Matt's CASE WHEN, what's the record count? If still 141, on top of what other commenters say, it's not impossible the tool where you output truncates records. 141 is a weird number for that, but who knows (e.g. like SSMS output max record count or similar)

Comment: Left outer join and lose the condition on id2 being null. Your words and your query don't match...

Comment: Mark - I am using SSMS. The source table underlying Query1 and Query2 has a large row count (39 million) but this has not been an issue so far.

Comment: LoztInSpace - Thank you for your suggestion which I tried. Removing the NULL condition and replacing LEFT JOIN with LEFT OUTER JOIN returns all of the records in CTE1 (all 50,496 of them), not just those that are in CTE1 but not CTE2, which is what I am after.

Comment: Mark - Yes with Matt's CASE WHEN, the record count is still 141 and the rogue Patient_ID does not appear as the first item. However, if I insert the condition looking for the specific ID as follows:

SELECT 
  [Patient_ID]
 ,[Condition_Code]
FROM CTE3
WHERE [Patient_ID] = 13413953
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Patient_ID] = 13413953 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

then I do get the single record returned like so (which I have just copied and pasted directly):

13413953 DEM

(where DEM is the condition code)

Comment: Update: The previous code posted which focused on the join between CTE1 and CTE2 has turned out to be a red herring. After further digging I have found that the problem lies in the query underlying CTE1.  I will therefore edit the question to re-state the position with the benefit of the new finding.

Comment: Looks pretty crazy to me still. We're going to need to see the code. What version of SQL Server? (`SELECT @@VERSION`)?